# Aliasing targets in boost build

Tags: c++, boost-build

Having the following Jamfiles, assume I also have a [root/p2/exep2/Jamfile] which uses libp1. I have globally unique names. So I would like to somewhat "alias" */LIBP1//libp1* as *libp1*.

Jamroot.jam:

```
build-project P1;
use-project LIBP1 : p1/libp1 ;
path-constant PROJECT_ROOT : . ;
```

Jamfile [root/p1/Jamfile]:

```
project P1
        : requirements
          [...]



build-project libp1 ;
build-project libX;
[...]
```

Jamfile [root/p1/libp1]:

```
lib libp1 : #sources
            [ glob *.cpp ]
          : # requirements
            <library>/site-config//sybase
          : #default-build
          : #usage-requirements
            <include>.
 ;
```

Jamfile [root/p2/exep2/Jamfile]:

```
 exe p2 :[...]
         <library>/LIBP1//libp1
```

how to only write the actual lib name ? as an alias ? as a constant ? I would like to have:

```
 <library>libp1
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want that?

Comment: There used to be makefiles. Those names are globally unique, about a dozen of libs. They used to be 'libXX' libXYZ'. I would just like to know if it is possible to keep it that way. Use-project refers to a jamfile, never to a specific target.

Comment: I tried alias "libp1 : /LIBP1//libp1 ;" but it does not work.

Comment: alias libp1 : /LIBP1//libp1 ; should work (without the quotes). As an alternative try alias : : : : <library>/LIBP1//libp1 ;

Comment: sorry, I meant "alias libp1 : /LIBP1//libp1 ;" I of course tried without the quotes. Maybe there was a name conflict ? I'll try again...